# String "????" converts to "data" in Python

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, sentinel

While writing a small Python script, I noticed that when the string `"????"` is passed as a command-line argument, it converts to `"data"` during program execution. Now, I am unsure whether this is a string or some other kind of data type. Finding information on this has been tricky, given the search terms.

Why does this happen and what does it mean?

Comment: is there a file called `data` in the directory in which you are running the script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?` is a shell wildcard character, it matches any character (similar to `.` in a regular expression). So an unquoted `????` expands to all filenames with 4 characters. `data` is presumably the first such filename alphabetically in your directory.

See the output of

```
echo ????
```

If you want to pass `????` literally to the script, quote it.

```
python yourscript.py '????'
```

Comment: Boy, I feel silly. Funnily enough, I was attempting to use '?' as a wildcard character within the script itself. I can't guarantee that any argument will be passed quoted, so I'll have to use a different character. Thank you!